# 3D manipulator stuck on left side of split viewport

Tags: 3d-manipulator

I'm using Blender 2.8. I split my viewport but accidentally moved the 3D manipulator to the right side- I don't know how I moved it nor how to move it back to the left side. The ride side is in rendered view. When I try to use the measure tool,  manipulator and other tools on the left side, I get an alert that says 'gizmo hidden in this view'.

Comment: Can you show on picture whats wrong ? Or go to C:\Users\UserName\Application Data\Blender Foundation\Blender and delete folder 2.8X

Comment: @SlobodanVidovic There is no need to delete that folder, it wouldn't fix the described problem anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you've hidden the gizmos in the left viewport, which is why the *Move* gizmo is invisible and the *Measure* tool gives you an error message. Enable them by clicking the *Show Gizmos* icon shown below.

[image: Show Gizmos]

Ensure that the following options are enabled in *Viewport Gizmos*.

[image: Viewport Gizmos options]

---

The exact error message is "Gizmos hidden in this view" which is printed by `view3d_ruler_add_invoke()` ([`view3d_gizmo_ruler.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/space_view3d/view3d_gizmo_ruler.c)) when the *Measure* tool is used and `v3d->gizmo_flag` has the `V3D_GIZMO_HIDE` or `V3D_GIZMO_HIDE_TOOL` flags set. `V3D_GIZMO_HIDE` is set when *Show Gizmos* is disabled and `V3D_GIZMO_HIDE_TOOL` when *Active Tools* in the *Viewport Gizmos* options is deactivated.